# help to get 17% to 100% for batch class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, apex-email-service

[image: This is the line of code where it shows error]

I am new in SFDC i need to get 100% code coverage for this batch class currently it has 17% and i am facing problem in every `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();`as its showing red in developer console see below the

**Batch Class**

===============================================================================

```
global with sharing class InvoiceAutomationClass1 implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>
        {
            <b>public List<EmailTemplate> etemp {get;set;}
            public List<EmailTemplate> etemps {get;set;}
            public List<EmailTemplate> etempnuk {get;set;}
            public List<EmailTemplate> etemptech {get;set;}
            public List<EmailTemplate> etemprgtech{get;set;}</b>
            global  List<Id> Invsend = new List<Id> ();
            global  List<Id> ListInv = new List<Id> ();
            global  List<Id> ListInv1 = new List<Id>();
            global  List<Id> Invrem = new List<Id> ();

        global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)

        {
           return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Ageing__c,Invoice_Billing_Entity__c,Status_Reference__c,Contact_Person__c,Contact_Email__c,Invoice_Email_Status__c from Invoice__c where (Ageing__c=-26 And Status_Reference__c= 'Raised' And Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Invoice Ok To Send') 
                                                                                    or (Ageing__c=-12 And Status_Reference__c= 'Raised' And Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Reminder For Payment')
                                                                                    or (Ageing__c=1 And Status_Reference__c= 'Pending' And Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Due Reminder')
                                                                                    or (Ageing__c=30 And Status_Reference__c= 'Pending' And Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Extra Charges Email')
                                                                                    or (Ageing__c=45 And Status_Reference__c='Pending' And Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Account Cancel')]);
        }


        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,list<Invoice__c > scope) {

                List<Invoice__c> InvUpdateList = New List<Invoice__c>();
                List<EmailTemplate> etemp=[Select Id,Name,HtmlValue, Body,Subject  From EmailTemplate where name='Invoice Email' limit 1 ];
                List<EmailTemplate> etemps=[Select Id,Name,HtmlValue, Body,Subject  From EmailTemplate where name='Pending Invoice Email' limit 1 ];
                List<EmailTemplate> etempnuk=[Select Id,Name,HtmlValue, Body,Subject  From EmailTemplate where name='NON_UK_Invoice_Email_Templete' limit 1 ];
                List<EmailTemplate> etemptech=[Select Id,Name,HtmlValue, Body,Subject  From EmailTemplate where name='UK Tech Invoice Template' limit 1 ];
                List<EmailTemplate> etemprgtech=[Select Id,Name,HtmlValue, Body,Subject  From EmailTemplate where name='RG Tech Invoice Template' limit 1 ];

        for(Invoice__c  inv:scope) {

             If(inv.Ageing__c==-26 && inv.Status_Reference__c== 'Raised' && inv.Invoice_Email_Status__c== 'Invoice Ok To Send') {
                    <b>if(inv.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c=='RG India'){
                        // Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
                        **Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +etemp);
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +ListInv);
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +Invsend);
                        //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                        //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                        mail.setTemplateId(etemp[0].id);
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                        mail.setUseSignature(false);
                        mail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                        mail.setBccSender(false);
                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                        mail.setWhatId(inv.id);
                        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});** 
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +r);  
                        system.debug('-----RG India---=' +inv.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c);    

                    }else if(inv.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c=='RG UK'){
                        // Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +etemp);
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +ListInv);
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +Invsend);
                        //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                        //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                        mail.setTemplateId(etempnuk[0].id);
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                        mail.setUseSignature(false);
                        mail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                        mail.setBccSender(false);
                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                        mail.setWhatId(inv.id);
                        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +r);    
                        system.debug('-----RG UK---=' +inv.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c); 

                    }else if(inv.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c=='RG Tech'){
                        // Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +etemp);
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +ListInv);
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +Invsend);
                        //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                        //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                        mail.setTemplateId(etemprgtech[0].id);
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                        mail.setUseSignature(false);
                        mail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                        mail.setBccSender(false);
                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                        mail.setWhatId(inv.id);
                        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +r);   
                        system.debug('-----RG Tech---=' +inv.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c);  

                    }else{
                        // Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +etemp);
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +ListInv);
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +Invsend);
                        //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                        //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                        mail.setTemplateId(etemptech[0].id);
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                        mail.setUseSignature(false);
                        mail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                        mail.setBccSender(false);
                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                        mail.setWhatId(inv.id);
                        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
                        system.debug('-----Email---=' +r);  
                        system.debug('-----UK Tech---=' +inv.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c);   
                    }
                        inv.Invoice_Email_Status__c='Reminder For Payment';
                        InvUpdateList.add(inv);
                        system.debug('-----Invoice Update Reminder For Payment---=' +InvUpdateList);

            }</b>

        else if (inv.Ageing__c==-12 && inv.Status_Reference__c== 'Raised' && inv.Invoice_Email_Status__c== 'Reminder For Payment'){

                //  ListInv1.add(inv.id);
                //  Invrem.add(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +etemp);
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +ListInv);
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +Invsend);
                //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                mail.setTemplateId(etemps[0].id);
                mail.setTargetObjectId(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                mail.setUseSignature(false);
                mail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                mail.setBccSender(false);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                mail.setWhatId(inv.id);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +r);   
                inv.Invoice_Email_Status__c='Due Reminder'; 
                InvUpdateList.add(inv);
                system.debug('-----Invoice Update Due Reminder---=' +InvUpdateList);

        }

        else if (inv.Ageing__c==1 && inv.Status_Reference__c== 'Pending' && inv.Invoice_Email_Status__c== 'Due Reminder'){

                //  ListInv1.add(inv.id);
                //  Invrem.add(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +etemp);
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +ListInv);
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +Invsend);
                //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                mail.setTemplateId(etemps[0].id);
                mail.setTargetObjectId(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                mail.setUseSignature(false);
                mail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                mail.setBccSender(false);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                mail.setWhatId(inv.id);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +r);    
                inv.Invoice_Email_Status__c='Extra Charges Email'; 
                InvUpdateList.add(inv);
                system.debug('-----Invoice Update Extra Charges Email---=' +InvUpdateList);

        }


        else if (inv.Ageing__c==30 && inv.Status_Reference__c== 'Pending' && inv.Invoice_Email_Status__c== 'Extra Charges Email'){

                //  ListInv1.add(inv.id);
                //  Invrem.add(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +etemp);
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +ListInv);
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +Invsend);
                //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                mail.setTemplateId(etemps[0].id);
                mail.setTargetObjectId(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                mail.setUseSignature(false);
                mail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                mail.setBccSender(false);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                mail.setWhatId(inv.id);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +r);   
                inv.Invoice_Email_Status__c='Account Cancel'; 
                InvUpdateList.add(inv);
                system.debug('-----Invoice Update Account Cancel---=' +InvUpdateList);

        }


        else if (inv.Ageing__c==45 && inv.Status_Reference__c== 'Pending' && inv.Invoice_Email_Status__c== 'Account Cancel'){

                //  ListInv1.add(inv.id);
                //  Invrem.add(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +etemp);
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +ListInv);
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +Invsend);
                //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                mail.setTemplateId(etemps[0].id);
                mail.setTargetObjectId(inv.Contact_Person__c);
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                mail.setUseSignature(false);
                mail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                mail.setBccSender(false);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                mail.setWhatId(inv.id);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
                system.debug('-----Email---=' +r);    

        }


        }
        if(InvUpdateList.size()>0){
        update InvUpdateList;
        system.debug('-----Invoice Update---=' +InvUpdateList);
        }
        system.debug('-----Invoice Update---=' +InvUpdateList);

        }

        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {




        }

        }
```

==================================**Test Class**========================================

```
@isTest
  private class Test_InvoiceAutomationClass1 { 
      private Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] sent; 
static testMethod void InvoiceAutomationClass1_TestMethod (){
     List<Invoice__c> invList = new List<Invoice__c>(); 
      Messaging.Singleemailmessage testEmail;
      List<Messaging.Sendemailresult> testEmailResults;

     Profile prof = [select id from profile where name='system Administrator'];
     User usr = new User(alias = 'usr', email='us.name@vmail.com',
                emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='lstname',
                timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',
                languagelocalekey='en_US',
                localesidkey='en_US', profileid = prof.Id,
                username='testuser128@testorg.com');
                insert usr;
   Account acc = new Account(name='testName', Ownerid = usr.id);
   insert acc ;


        Contract Contr=new Contract();
            Contr.AccountId=acc.Id;
            Contr.Status='Draft';
            Insert Contr;

            Contact con = new Contact(Email='vivek.istarmca@gmail.com',LastName='shukla',FirstName='Abhinav');
            insert con;


        for(integer i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        Invoice__c Invc=new Invoice__c();
            Invc.Contract__c=Contr.id;
            Invc.Vertical__c='PS';
            Invc.InvoiceDate__c=system.today();
            Invc.Credit_Days__c=10;
            Invc.Currency__c='USD';
            Invc.Term__c='Monthly';
            Invc.Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Reminder For Payment';
            Invc.Conversion_Rate_To_INR__c=100;
            Invc.Contact_Person__c= con.id;
            Invc.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c= 'RG UK';
            Invc.Conversion_Rate_To_USD__c=1.000000;
            Invc.Type__c='Fresh';
            Invc.Property_Name__c='TestMon';
            Invc.From__c=system.today()-20;
            Invc.To__c=system.today();
            invList.add(Invc);

            }
            insert invList;
             List<EmailTemplate> etemp=[Select Id,Name,HtmlValue, Body,Subject  From EmailTemplate where name='Invoice Email' limit 1 ];

              testEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                        //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                        //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                        testEmail.setTemplateId(etemp[0].id);
                        testEmail.setTargetObjectId(invList[0].Contact_Person__c);
                        testEmail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                        testEmail.setUseSignature(false);
                        testEmail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                        testEmail.setBccSender(false);
                        testEmail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                        testEmail.setWhatId(invList[0].id);

            testEmailResults = 
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {testEmail}); 

   Test.StartTest();
        CallingInvoiceAutomationClass1 p = new CallingInvoiceAutomationClass1();
            String sch = '0 0 8 13 2 ?';
            system.schedule('One Time Pro', sch, p);

        InvoiceAutomationClass1 objBatch = new InvoiceAutomationClass1();
            Integer batchSize = 10;  
            Database.QueryLocator ql = objBatch.start(null);
            objBatch.execute(null,invList);
            objBatch.Finish(null);
            ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(objBatch,batchSize );
            Integer emailbefore = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
            System.assertEquals(emailbefore, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
    Test.StopTest();

  }

}
```

**Updated Test Class but still get 17% coverage**=========================================================================

I have change the cod like below for test class but still its shows 17% coverage in batch class. kindly suggest...!! Thanks

```
  @isTest 
  private class Test_InvoiceAutomationClass1 { 
      private Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] sent; 
      static testMethod void InvoiceAutomationClass1_TestMethod (){
      List<Invoice__c> invList = new List<Invoice__c>(); 
      Messaging.Singleemailmessage testEmail;
      List<Messaging.Sendemailresult> testEmailResults;

     Profile prof = [select id from profile where name='system Administrator'];
     User usr = new User(alias = 'usr', email='us.name@vmail.com',
                emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='lstname',
                timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',
                languagelocalekey='en_US',
                localesidkey='en_US', profileid = prof.Id,
                username='testuser128@testorg.com');
                insert usr;
   Account acc = new Account(name='testName', Ownerid = usr.id);
   insert acc ;       

            Contract Contr=new Contract();
            Contr.AccountId=acc.Id;
            Contr.Status='Draft';
            Insert Contr;

            Contact con = new Contact(Email='vivek.istarmca@gmail.com',LastName='shukla',FirstName='Abhinav');
            insert con;


            Invoice__c Invc=new Invoice__c();
            Invc.Contract__c=Contr.id;            
            Invc.Vertical__c='PS';
            Invc.InvoiceDate__c = system.today();
            Invc.Invoice_Due_Date__c = date.newinstance(2015, 5, 13);
            //Invc.Invoice_Due_Date__c = date.today() + 26;
            Invc.Invoice_Status__c  = 'Raised';
            Invc.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c = 'RG India';
            Invc.Credit_Days__c=10;
            Invc.Currency__c='USD';
            Invc.Term__c='Monthly';
            Invc.Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Invoice Ok To Send';
            Invc.Conversion_Rate_To_INR__c=100;
            Invc.Contact_Person__c= con.id;
            Invc.Conversion_Rate_To_USD__c=1.000000;
            Invc.Type__c='Fresh';
            Invc.Property_Name__c='TestMon';
            Invc.From__c=system.today()-20;
            Invc.To__c=system.today();
            invList.add(Invc);            

           Invoice__c Invc1=new Invoice__c();
            Invc1.Contract__c=Contr.id;            
            Invc1.Vertical__c='PS';
            Invc1.InvoiceDate__c = system.today();
            Invc1.Invoice_Due_Date__c = date.newinstance(2015, 5, 13);
            //Invc1.Invoice_Due_Date__c = date.today() + 26;
            Invc1.Invoice_Status__c  = 'Raised';
            Invc1.Credit_Days__c=10;
            Invc1.Currency__c='USD';
            Invc1.Term__c='Monthly';
            Invc1.Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Invoice Ok To Send';
            Invc1.Conversion_Rate_To_INR__c=100;
            Invc1.Contact_Person__c= con.id;
            Invc1.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c= 'RG UK';
            Invc1.Conversion_Rate_To_USD__c=1.000000;
            Invc1.Type__c='Fresh';
            Invc1.Property_Name__c='TestMon';
            Invc1.From__c=system.today()-20;
            Invc1.To__c=system.today();
            invList.add(Invc1);  

             Invoice__c Invc2=new Invoice__c();
            Invc2.Contract__c=Contr.id;            
            Invc2.Vertical__c='PS';
            Invc2.InvoiceDate__c = system.today();
            Invc2.Invoice_Due_Date__c = date.newinstance(2015, 5, 13);
            //Invc2.Invoice_Due_Date__c = date.today() + 26;
            Invc2.Invoice_Status__c  = 'Raised';
            Invc2.Credit_Days__c=10;
            Invc2.Currency__c='USD';
            Invc2.Term__c='Monthly';
            Invc2.Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Invoice Ok To Send';
            Invc2.Conversion_Rate_To_INR__c=100;
            Invc2.Contact_Person__c= con.id;
            Invc2.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c= 'RG Tech';
            Invc2.Conversion_Rate_To_USD__c=1.000000;
            Invc2.Type__c='Fresh';
            Invc2.Property_Name__c='TestMon';
            Invc2.From__c=system.today()-20;
            Invc2.To__c=system.today();
            invList.add(Invc2);  

             Invoice__c Invc3=new Invoice__c();
            Invc3.Contract__c=Contr.id;            
            Invc3.Vertical__c='PS';
            Invc3.InvoiceDate__c = system.today();
            Invc3.Invoice_Due_Date__c = date.newinstance(2015, 5, 13);
            //Invc3.Invoice_Due_Date__c = date.today() + 26;
            Invc3.Invoice_Status__c  = 'Raised';
            Invc3.Credit_Days__c=10;
            Invc3.Currency__c='USD';
            Invc3.Term__c='Monthly';
            Invc3.Invoice_Email_Status__c= 'Invoice Ok To Send';
            Invc3.Conversion_Rate_To_INR__c=100;
            Invc3.Contact_Person__c= con.id;
            Invc3.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c= 'UK Tech';
            Invc3.Conversion_Rate_To_USD__c=1.000000;
            Invc3.Type__c='Fresh';
            Invc3.Property_Name__c='TestMon';
            Invc3.From__c=system.today()-20;
            Invc3.To__c=system.today();
            invList.add(Invc3);  

            insert invList;

             List<EmailTemplate> etemp=[Select Id,Name,HtmlValue, Body,Subject  From EmailTemplate where name='Invoice Email' limit 1 ];

              testEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                        //mail.setTemplateId('etemp');
                        //mail.setTemplateId('00XO0000000Lygn');
                        testEmail.setTemplateId(etemp[0].id);
                        testEmail.setTargetObjectId(invList[0].Contact_Person__c);
                        testEmail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Receivable');
                        testEmail.setUseSignature(false);
                        testEmail.setReplyTo('abhinav.shukla@rategain.com');
                        testEmail.setBccSender(false);
                        testEmail.setSaveAsActivity(True);
                        testEmail.setWhatId(invList[0].id);

            testEmailResults = 
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {testEmail}); 

   Test.StartTest();
        CallingInvoiceAutomationClass1 p = new CallingInvoiceAutomationClass1();
            String sch = '0 0 8 13 2 ?';
            system.schedule('One Time Pro', sch, p);

        InvoiceAutomationClass1 objBatch = new InvoiceAutomationClass1();
            Integer batchSize = 10;  
            Database.QueryLocator ql = objBatch.start(null);
            objBatch.execute(null,invList);
            objBatch.Finish(null);
            ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(objBatch,batchSize );
            Integer emailbefore = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
            System.assertEquals(emailbefore, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
    Test.StopTest();

  }

}
```

Comment: the error that you are facing is in the batch class or in the test class? can you please share that error as well (in developer console you should be able to view it under the 'Problems" tab)? Also, make sure your invoice records are created such that all if conditions are met, i dont see ageing, status reference fields being set.

Comment: Hi Rajiv, i am facing problem in test class. my test class not able to cover the   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

Answer (score 0):

You are currently only ever testing with `Invc.Invoice_Billing_Entity__c= 'RG UK'`, so in your trigger the `if` block will never go down the paths for `'RG India'` or `'RG Tech'`.

You need to update your test to included `Invoice__c` objects with the `Invoice_Billing_Entity__c` field values to test all the path of that `if` statement. That should increase your test coverage.

Answer (score -3):

I am sharing you the snapshot of the class.

[image: I am sending the snapshot.]

Comment: Please see my answer regarding this. It's not the Messaging causing the issue.

Comment: Would yo be able to update this to the question too ? It'll be easier for people to understand and help you if you have centralized all information in a single place (=> at the question).